# The tooltip of the Bûche de Noël hat shows “�” characters

Tags: bug, winter-bash, tooltips, unicode, winter-bash-2020

The tooltip for *Bûche de Noël* in the Winter Bash modal has an encoding issue: accented characters are shown as `�`.

[image: The tooltip for “Bûche de Noël” says “B�che de No�l”.]

Comment: Confirm that, happens to me as well.